# URLRequest timeoutInterval for entire call

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

Documentation states, that `timeoutInterval` for `URLRequest` is being measured not only from the start of the request, but anytime an event like new data is received occurs, time idle is being counted from 0.
Quote from documentation:

> Hence, when an instance of load activity occurs (e.g. bytes are received from the network for a request), the idle interval for a request is reset to 0.

I wanted to ask if there is some other mechanism that doesn't restart when such event occurs, but simply gives a time from the beginning to the end, and if it takes longer then request is invalidated. I know that this can be easily achieved using `dispatchAfter`, just wanted to make sure there is no existing mechanism for this, so that I can use it.

Comment: Configure the `timeoutIntervalForResource` value on your [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1408153-timeoutintervalforresource)

Comment: Thanks. This gives some new view to this, but I was actually looking for per request solution. If there is nothing like this, I will just implement it myself. But `timeoutIntervalForResource` is also something worth knowing.